# kitchen sink plumbing hook up

Tags: sink

I am remodeling and I have to replace kitchen cabinets and sink, I was thinking if I had a set up like I do for my washing machine,-in wall faucets and drain it would make it easy to disconnect and move sink out to replace the bad floor then put it back until the new cabinets come in.   do they make something like this, is it a good idea?

Comment: Are you asking if you can install shutoff valves under your sink? If that's the case, then yes. There should be shutoff valves under the sink.

Comment: no I am asking if I can mount the drain and water supply in the wall just like the washer hookups

Comment: It is fine to have plumbing in walls.  Can you give a picture or diagram?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go through this effort (rather than just capping off the lines), then you should just install the lines into the walls (if they aren't already).

[image: plumbing in walls]

Normally you'd just cap the lines off until you're ready to hook everything up (as seen in my picture above), but there's nothing stopping you from putting valves on instead of caps, which is a great idea anyway (it makes it easier to hook up, service later, etc).

With the pipes in the walls, you can freely work on the floor and install cabinets without worrying about them (and as you can see in this photo, it was before I had flooring or cabinets in).

---

Here's the same connections (with valves) after installing cabinets and the new sink:

[image]

Nothing stops you from using valves instead of caps, though it does require cutting a bigger hole in the cabinet to install. Depending on your cabinet style you may or may not like this -- in my case these are pretty cheap cabinets installed in a laundry room in the basement, I wasn't too worried.

Just be sure you don't accidentally knock the vales open while you're working, or you'll ruin the floor that you're not even finished installing yet!

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to have an inaccessible trap for a kitchen sink. That probably violates code for the clean-out somehow. Yes, it will work, however there will also be an air gap where you shoved the drain into the standpipe leading to bad smell if the trap has goo in it. It's OK for washing machines because there's no food waste and a good dose of soap every time.

Answer (score 0):

Not really necessary.  There should be shutoff valves under the sink.  Usually those can be turned off (verify that once they are no water comes out of the faucet) and the pipes up to the faucet can be disconnected.  The same is true with the waste lines.  They normally have screw fittings that can be removed and reassembled.

A wall box like a washer uses won't work for a sink.  A sink has the trap under it, a washer box has the trap hidden in the wall.  A washer pumps water up and out, a sink relies on gravity.  There can be no openings in the pipe after the trap, doing so will allow sewer gases into the home.

In commercial spaces and in some countries it is common to have a drain (with trap) on the floor, and the fixtures have pipes that empty out above the drain.  This can be messy and is rarely done in residential.

Comment: There are no shut off valves under the sink, it is old copper pipe and all joints are soldered,  there is a cold water shut off in the cellar but it is frozen open, and there is none for the hot water pipe to the sink.

Comment: If that is the case I would highly recommend before going much further with the renovation you make a priority to install proper water controls in the house. There will be a shutoff valve at the water meter which requires a special tool (typically) to turn. Imagine you're working on something and a pipe being old gets hit and breaks now you have to wait until someone has the tool to turn off the water supply to the house to arrive to stop the flooding. *speaking from experience at a rental, it REALLY sucks*

Comment: I have a plumber coming in soon to replace some pipes I am just trying to figure out how to have a sink to use, the floor is being taken up on Feb 24 so the sink has to be out, then it will be 2 weeks before cabinets come, then after the new cabinets another couple of weeks before the counter, so I would like to be able to sit the old sink and counter on top of the new cabinets and hook it up to use while I wait.  I can shut off the whole house by shutting off the pump.

Comment: Talk to your plumber about this. The water supplies should have shut offs and the drains must have traps and proper venting.  All drains are similar, but some washer drains are open stacks over a trap and definitely not appropriate for a kitchen sink.